# How to prevent my app to be closed by the infamous GbPlugin?

Tags: windows, delphi

In some customers my app is being closed by a bizarre plugin called 'GBPlugin' ; it is installed by some brazillian bank websites to 'protect' customers from scams. But indeed what the plugin does is to force close applications that seems 'supicious' using its own never clear judgements.

I have a OnCloseQuery method that shows a confirmation dialog , but the plugin bypass it and force closes the app as soon as it is opened.

The problem does not happen with all customers, in some cases the plugin let my application run without problems, other cases it closes the app without warning.

My EXE file is crypted in order to difficult cracking and i've found this is one of the factors used to judge an app like suspicious.

I already tried to counter-attack by closing the plugin process when my app is activated, but as soon as it closed, another instance is opened and then closes my app.

Is there a way to prevent an app from being closed for another process ?

Comment: Require users that have the plugin to run your application elevated. Can't guess if it would really help though..

Comment: [How create a unterminable process in Windows](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/create-a-unterminable-process-in-windows)

Comment: Get your customers to stop running this program.

Comment: Or have your customers add an exception to this plugin which ignores your application - if it has that option. Otherwise, I second David's recommendation.

Comment: @JerryDodge There is not. This plug-in caused a big problem to [Windows 7 updates](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2839011/en-us) in Brazil some time ago that lead the computer to not recover from a restart. More info about it check this [link](http://insanebits.blogspot.com.br/2007/04/g-buster-browser-defense-analysis-and.html)

Comment: Your application should be signed and ask the plugin developer to whitelist your program.

Comment: You cannot prevent closing - you only may hope for a re-start, but re-starting means all windows closed, all entered data lost, et cetera. It would be even worse. All you can do not is displaying farewell message 'Program "GBPlugin" is killing program "Yours"' so that users would not home to ask about their lost work. In the meantime ask your users to install virtual machine like VirtualBox, MWare, VirtualPC (known as Windows 7 XP Mode) where your program would work in a clean environment without that crazy killer chasing you.

Comment: Do not try to kill GBPlugin or ask your users to do so. It's a _sheet_, I know, but Brazilian internet banking websites will not allow the user to login if the plugin is not running, and will ask them to reinstall it.

Comment: @JefreySobreiraSantos There are hundreds of complains about this 'plugin' , just search. It's a ridiculous 'protection', things like this only happens in this fantastic place called Brazil : http://www.michaelrigo.com/2015/01/como-remover-gbuster-na-unha.html

Comment: @delphirules i know these plugins sucks, but we can't ask our users to close or uninstall it, as hardly our apps are more important than their personal bank accounts (that they will not be able to access anymore if they do so). The article you mentioned states that, for not having to go physically to the bank agency, we must learn to live with these plugins or install it on a virtual machine. Let's say that some (most?) computers users does not even know what a virtual machine is. BTW, what programming language and what crypter are you using?

Comment: @JefreySobreiraSantos I use Delphi with a combination of AsProtect and Code Virtualization. Somehow when i sign the final crypted product, it crashes on startup.

Comment: Understood. Is AsProtect safe now? I've seem lots of tools to unpack it automatically. Also, I think it's worthy to fill a bug report/support ticket/contact email with them telling about the problem with signed executables...

Comment: @JefreySobreiraSantos Asprotect alone is not safe. What worked for me for the last 3 years is a combination of several anti-cracking methods, along with lots of checks inside the code.

Answer (score 2):

Digitally sign your program.
GBPlugin dont close signed executables.

Here a tutorial ( in portuguese ):
http://www.ericksasse.com.br/como-assinar-digitalmente-seus-aplicativos/

Comment: Due to anti-cracking solutions i use, i can't sign my EXE.

Comment: Looks like your anti-cracking solution is at least indirectly responsible for the fact that your customers cannot run your program.

Comment: @UweRaabe Maybe, but i prefer some people can't use my app because GbPlugin block it than it be cracked and everybody uses it free :p